# CSS3 is not working in SAP BSP

Tags: css, sap-bsp

I am trying to use css3 styles(like border-radius,box-shadow) in my bsp application.But these new styles are not applied in BSP. I have tried by replacing the BSP  tag to  too.But the existed elments(like table,listbox etc.) do nto work properly.The entire alignment has been destroyed. Can I know the reason?

Comment: Greetings, can you provide the code you use in your BSP ?

Comment: I got the problem why css3 is not working in bsp.There are not appending !DOCTYPE tag at before header tag.Of course,we can add that at the top of our page.But destroys other element layout..that is the problem...Can you analyze the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you want to use the standard BSP libraries *and* you want to use css3 ? I am not sure that can be done. I would drop the standard libraries and start using the jQuery UI and Bootstrap libraries.

Especially as the standard BSP libraries are aging very badly.